# How to make this different type of hat for a variable?

Tags: symbols

I am currently reading a math paper, and one of the variables has this sort of hat on it:

[image]

I have tried to find its code using detexify and by looking at several manuals, but I was unable to do so. Can anyone please tell me what the code is for this type of hat is?

Thank you very much.

Comment: That's just `$\breve{a}$`.

Comment: @campa Yes, thank you very much.

Comment: @campa Would you like to post this as an answer, or should I delete the question?

Comment: I've marked this for duplicate, so if the linked answer is OK for you you should be able to "accept" the duplicate.

Comment: @campa Ah yes I just needed to refresh the page. Thank you again!